# Formula for Data Comparison

Tags: excel

I am looking for a formula that will populate a cell based on yesterday's day value for last month.

Please see my example:

```
                          Prior Month Comparison |       |      |   
                                  5-Jul          | 5-Aug |4-Aug |    5-Jul
Total Number of Records:          10             |    25 |   7  |    10
Total Records Sold:               5              |    3  |   0  |... 5
```

I have all of July records to the right of my August records. I might have to use arrays so I'm not sure what would be the best approach.

I have looked into index/match but I'm not sure how to best apply this formula. I am available to any formula that will help me fill out my Prior Month Comparison column.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HLOOKUP:

```
=HLOOKUP($B$1,C:E,ROW(),FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: I like this formula but it only works if my data is at the top of the row. Is there a way to modify this formula for data that's not included in the top row?

Comment: Wow... I apologize. You're answer is valid. I didn't know that I can change "Row()" to the row number I would like to extract!!

Comment: If you leave `ROW()` blank it returns the row number in which the formula is found, so dragging down it would return `2` then `3` etc.